# Magento 1.6.2.0 PayPal Bug - Billing address request is not enabled for merchant (#11601: Request for billing address failed)

Tags: magento-1.6

I'm working on a project with Magento 1.6.2.0 and we are experiencing an issue related to PayPal.

It says:

```
Billing address request is not enabled for merchant (#11601: Request for billing address failed).
```

A possible solution for this matter can be found on Stackexchange, however those answers seem to be for Magento 1.9. Older Magento versions don't have the needed system nodes to display configuration settings.

What I'm planning to do is to exctract PayPal Module Files from an upgraded Magento 1.9.x and put them into my own custom module and extend/rewrite Magento PayPal Module Version (from 1.6.2.0).

What I've found is that there are Source Files that needs to be properly rewritten, which wasn't a big issue.

Eventually I've managed to implement the needed System Node Field and set it to 0 (Require Billing Address). I've managed to include my upgraded `Checkout.php` File that handles `setRequireBillingAdress(1)` and implemented all needed constants and properties.

However, PayPal Api still returns the error, that I'm getting above.

How could I technically solve this without trying to update the whole Shop?